# XAML designer "Could not load file or assembly Autofac 4.1" in App.xaml of UWP application using MVVMLight

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvm-light, autofac

Starting with a blank Universal Windows Application I added Autofac 4.1, Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator 4.0 and MvvmLightLibs 5.3. I then created the following ViewModelLocator class.

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace UwpTest
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }
        public static bool IsBuilt { get; set; }

        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            if (!IsBuilt)
            {
                var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                builder.RegisterType<DialogService>().As<IDialogService>();
                builder.RegisterType<NavigationService>().As<INavigationService>();

                Container = builder.Build();

                IsBuilt = true;
            }

            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(Container));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the App.xaml I added the view model locator as a resource.

```
<Application
    x:Class="UwpTest.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UwpTest"
    RequestedTheme="Light">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

At this point I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Everything works fine at run time, but not at design time. I have double check that all packages have been restored. How can I find the location that the designer is attempting to load the Autofac dll from? Or what am I missing about how the project is setup?

I have already been though the [MSDN guide to troubleshooting design time issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934(v=vs.110).aspx), tried to debug the issue using a second instance of Visual Studio, and searched for answer in every way I can think of.

Repo with repo of the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/elanderson/AutofacMvvmLightTest).

Comment: Given this is specifically a design time issue, have you followed steps like in [the MSDN guide to troubleshooting design time issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934(v=vs.110).aspx) or searched for other answers about load failures in design time?

Comment: I have up to trying to attach a debugger using another instance of Visual Studio. I had not success with any of them.

Comment: You should probably update your question with info about stuff you've already tried so people know where to start looking and not redo work you've already done.

Comment: Great I idea it has been updated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue, it works well on my side. Did you update the .Net Core to the newest 5.2.2?

Comment: I did. I created a repo [here](https://github.com/elanderson/AutofacMvvmLightTest) that shows the issue. Open the App.xaml and build the application and it will show the error on line 8. Build will complete successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your [project](https://github.com/elanderson/AutofacMvvmLightTest) uploaded I reproduced your issue.  The solution for resolving this error is easy, just remove the [Autofac 4.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/) package it will be fine.

This is because when you install the [Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator/) NuGet package, it will help you install the dependencies which contain the `Autofac` package at the same time. You don't need to install the `Autofac` package by yourself.  When you installed `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator 4.0.0` it will help you install `Autofac 3.5.0`. If you install another version `Autofac` package it may lead ambiguity.

If you do want add two packages at the same time, please update the `Autofac` version from `4.1.1` to `3.5.0`. And it will also be fine, but I don't think it is necessary.

For how I know the `Auofac` is version `3.5.0` please see the following picture. If you tried to install the `Autofac 4.11` after the `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator 4.0.0` installed, you will get a update prompt about `Autofac` from `3.5.0` to `4.1.1`.

[image]

Comment: The package gives this as dependency: Autofac (>= 3.5.0 && < 5.0.0), so it shouldn't be a problem to upgrade to 4.1.1

Comment: @Bart, `Autofac` is last updated in `Thursday, September 22, 2016`, `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator` is last updated in `Tuesday, June 28, 2016`.  The update supports for `Auofac` of `Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator` not available is possible. The dependency shows the at least version request. In other word, `Auofac 5.0.0` now is not exists ,right? This may be the version future supports.

Comment: I tried using a bindingredirect, but the designer doesn't seem to respect that either. Not sure if it's a bug in VS or another issue. Interesting case ... but gotta leave for work now.

Comment: I agree that your suggestion does make the error go away and will accept it as the answer, but the Autofac 4 series is where support was added for .NET Standard 1.1 based on the [release notes](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Release-Notes). I would love to know why this setup up doesn't work, or a work around.

Comment: @elanderson ,it seems like this package can work alone, not with `CommonServiceLocator`. You can also submit your [issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues) here for more replies.